# xdg-open from within a snap

Tags: snap

How do I use xdg-open from within a snap? I found the "snapd-xdg-open" package, which apparently passes the URL to unity via dbus, which is all fine and good, but it appears that unity has no idea what to do with a URL? I get this error with snapd-xdg-open:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.canonical.SafeLauncher was not provided by any .service files
```

I found [this mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/snapcraft@lists.snapcraft.io/msg00076.html) thread, which seems to indicate that the fix is to install a package on the *host* system, which is, if I'm not mistaken, impossible to do with a snap, and also completely defeats the purpose of snappy, which renders that solution entirely useless.

If I want to open a URL on the host system, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It's far from a good solution because the end user has to install something by hand but it works for me.

I have used this in my snapcraft.yaml

```
parts:
  snapd-xdg-open:
    source: https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapd-xdg-open.git
    plugin: copy
    files:
      data/xdg-open: bin/xdg-open
    stage-packages:
      - dbus
```

Additionally you have to install snapd-xdg-open on the end users machine.

```
$ sudo apt-get install snapd-xdg-open
```

Comment: I still have this problem, how to implement your fix?

Answer (score 0):

Now, it works find with new plug

```
...
apps:
  ...
  plugs:
    - desktop
...
```

I tried `xdg-open` with a link to a website and it opens Firefox installed in the host.

If you don't activate `desktop` or alternative interface like `unity7`, you will get a permission denied message. Try with `snappy-debug.security scanlog` for details and hint on the fix.